# What is this keyboard shortcut control?

Tags: cocoa, controls, keyboard-shortcuts

I've seen this keyboard shortcut control in several apps. And I like it a lot!

**What is it?** 
Is it available for using in own applications?

[image]

Comment: You might be able to find out by poking around inside the app bundle (looking at Frameworks, for instance) and/or class-dumping its executable.

Comment: It's not that one, but MASShortcut is an excellent and easy shortcut recorder... It's also compatible with the MAS required samdbox!

Comment: Can you name a few of the apps you've seen using such a Shortcuts tab?

Comment: why not ask the developer of Caffeinated (one of the apps that uses it) on twitter... @curthard89

Comment: @combinatorial: That looks like the app shown in the question. Thanks; [I've sent him a tweet](https://twitter.com/boredzo/status/357623717028831233).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The control you are trying to find doesn't exist in the open source world. It is also not based on ShortcutRecorder, its completely custom.

Unfortunately I do not plan on open sourcing it, well, not any time soon if I do decide to open source it.

Thanks.

Comment: I knew it had to be custom. I think the OP was actually asking about the shortcuts in the app in particular not just the interface. Did you develop the control from scratch?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: What makes you think the questioner is asking about this app's default shortcuts?

Comment: Because it's not available in several apps.

Comment: Indeed it was completely from scratch, I did however see how ShortcutRecorder did the keyboard mapping which I tweaked to my needs. The system uses a custom event handling controller which is a wrapper around `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:mask:`, its actually fairly straight forward. The complex part was actually the drawing.

Comment: Ok, guessed as much. But if @PeterHosey is looking for Open Source MASShortcut is great too. It is used in one of his apps which has similar settings interface

Comment: @Curtis Hard, thanks for the direct answer! :) Nice to meet the developer of the great control. Even though it is not open-sourced.. Now that I know it is not available, I can think about writing same one for myself. Thanks again to everyone!

Comment: @CurtisHard do you offer paid licenses for the control at all, or is it completely private?

Comment: Its completely private and solely used in Caffeinated :)

Answer (score 3):

The Control you're referring to may be based on a Cocoa framework called [ShortcutRecorder](http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/) used to easily embed shortcuts and preferences to your apps. From the website:

> It comes with an Interface Builder palette, it is customizable and
>   resolution-independent, and it's already being used in applications.
>   Thanks to its BSD license, you can use it too, and adapt it if you
>   need to.

However, the control is [no longer compatible with Xcode4](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut#intro) and you may prefer newer alternatives like [MASShorcut](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut). The project is actively maintained on GitHub and has a good documentation. You can check out the [Demo here](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcutDemo).

There are also some other interesting related controls like [SS_PrefsController](http://mattgemmell.com/files/source/ssprefscontroller_docs/SS_PrefsController.html) that can help build the interface part.

[image: http://mattgemmell.com/files/source/previews/blog_preferences.png]

Comment: [Shortcut Recorder looks very different from what is shown in the question.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dFXPb.png)

Comment: @PeterHosey: I actually thought this question was asked in 2011, hence my inferences. AFAIK however, the shortcuts shown in the window are shortcuts common to email apps, and my best guess is that they're built using tools such as [MASShortcut](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut) or [BWToolkit](brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/), not used.